# printing an associative array in a combobox PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to print this array but it doesn't work...the combo box is empty. How can I print only the name's property in the combo box and the same time to get the NumClient in the option's value?

In my database is the client's table with 30 records then I would like to get the id(NumClient) and the name(Name) and put them in the combo box but I only want to print the Name and the id(NumClient) and I want to add it in the option's tag with the property value, for example

```
<option value="$array["NumClient"]">$array["Name"]</option>
<option value="1">Layana</option>
```

Any ideas?

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("bd_musique") or die(mysql_error());

$query="SELECT * from client";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo $query;

$array=array();

$i=0;
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $array=array($i,"NumClient"=>$rows["NumClient"], "Name"=>$rows["Name"]);
    $i++;
}

mysql_close($conn);

?>
 <select class="input-small" name="Client">
  <?php
    foreach($array as $b){
    print("<option value='$array[$b]['NumClient']'>".$array[$b]["Name"]."</option>"."  <br>");
    }           
   ?>
      /*    
       foreach($array as $cle=> $b){
       echo("<option value='$b'>".$cle.$b."</option>"."<br>");
        }
*/

</select>
```

Cheers

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: you're not appending to your $array in the while loop, you're reassigning $array each time. should be using $array[] =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not something like this, instead of having 3 different arrays, you can just use the loop to retrieve the resultset

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $array[] = array(
       'NumClient' => $rows["NumClient"],
       'Name' => $rows["Name"]
    );
}

//Print output
print '<select'>;
foreach($array as $value) {
   print("<option value={$value['NumClient']}>{$value['Name']}</option>");
}
print '</select>';
```

this will do the trick, using {} within a string "" allows you to print objects/arrays

**Update**

I did a local test, this is the code

```
$array[] = array(
   'NumClient' => 1,
   'Name' => 'Juan'
);

$array[] = array(
   'NumClient' => 2,
   'Name' => 'Luis'
);

$array[] = array(
   'NumClient' => 3,
   'Name' => 'Maria'
);



print '<select>';
foreach($array as $value) {
   print("<option value='{$value['NumClient']}'>{$value['Name']}</option>");
}
print '</select>';
```

this is the actual output
![Rendered combobox][1]

Be sure, to review your data source, maybe you're doing something else before

here's the resulting image i.stack.imgur.com/ilL6y.png

Comment: I got the records  in the combo box but all is empty...  I mean there are the spaces in white  but I can't see them.

Comment: have you tried to print $array after you populate it?

  print_r ( $array );

Comment: Now it works , it shows the records but the NumClient is empty. For exemple I try to get the option's value NumClient but it doesn't work.
<form name="form" action="next.php" method="get">
<select>
<?php
foreach($array as $value) {
 "<input name='numClient' type='hidden' value=\'{$value['NumClient']}\'>";
   print("<option name='num' value={$value['NumClient']}>{$value['Nom']}</option>");
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="envoyer" />
</form>

next.php

$NumClient=$_GET["num"];
$Num=$_GET["numClient"];

echo $NumClient;
echo $Num;

print_r($_GET);

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution, finally I did it:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("dbmusique", $conn);

    $query = "SELECT * from client";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $num= mysql_num_rows($result); 


    if ($num> 0) {
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array[] = array(
           'NumClient' => $row["NumClient"],
           'Name' => $row["Name"]
        );
     }
    }
    ?>  

<form name="form" action="next.php" method="get">
        <select name="numClient">
        <?php
        foreach($array as $value) {
          print("<option value=\"{$value['NumClient']}\">{$value['Name']}</option>");
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

next.php:

```
<?php
$NumClient=$_GET["numClient"];
echo $NumClient;
?>
```